# line numbers are disappear on production in the NLog logs

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, nlog

I configured NLog layout for having method name and line number by using ${callsite} parameters and it works well locally as below.

```
Application_Start(Global.asax.cs:33)
```

But it is changing to `Application_Start` without line numbers on production. I guess that it is because of it  can not access line numbers without .pdb files but i am using .NET 4.5 that makes possible to access line numbers via caller attributes without .pdb files. And i understand NLog haven't optimized itself for .NET 4.5.

Is there a way to put line numbers on production for .NET 4.5 with NLog ?

Comment: Ship PDB files would be the obvious fix. Can you do that?

Comment: That will not cause some performance overhead ?

Comment: Just shipping the files, I don't think so. If you have a lot of trace-level logging turned on, then there'll be an overhead..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NLog does not use the new attributes in .NET 4.5

It uses the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

This is evident from the [source code](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/LayoutRenderers/CallSiteLayoutRenderer.cs#L133).

As such, you need the .pdb files for the line numbers.

Comment: FYI, the caller info attributes aren't supported in NLog as that would be a breaking change (and another breaking change when there would be more caller info attributes added)

Answer (score 0):

NLog v5 adds support for using [Caller Information](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/caller-information)-Attributes, so adding [${callsite}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-layout-renderer)  will not require capture of full StackTrace and use of PDB-files.

Example of logging with Caller Info Member Attributes with NLog v5 [fluent-logger-API](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Logger-API):

```cs
_logger.ForInfoEvent()
       .Message("This is a fluent message {0}", "test")
       .Property("PropertyName", "PropertyValue")
       .Log();  // Log-method captures the callsite
```

Maybe consider to specify `${callsite:captureStackTrace=false}` to ensure NLog never automatically captures full StackTrace, when caller-member-information was not provided by the logging-statement.